# Existence and uniqueness of solution of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the initial value problem $(1)\left\{\begin{matrix}
y'(t)=y^2 &, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \\ 
y(0)=1 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$. Verify that the following theorem:

"Let $c>0$ and $f \in C([a,b] \times [y_0-c, y_0+c])$. If $f$ satisfies at $[a,b] \times [y_0-c, y_0+c])$ the Lipschtiz condition in respect to $y$, uniformly in respect of $t$, that means that:

$$\exists L \geq 0: \forall t \in [a,b] \ \forall y_1, y_2 \in [y_0-c,y_0+c]: \\ |f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)| \leq L |y_1-y_2|$$

then the initial value problem $\left\{\begin{matrix}
y'(t)=f(t,y(t)) &, a \leq t \leq b \\ 
y(a)=y_0 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$ is solved uniquely at least at the interval $[a,b']$ where with $A=\max_{a \leq t \leq b, y_0-c \leq y \leq y_0+c} |f(t,y)|$ we have that $b'=\min \{ b, a+ \frac{c}{A}\}$. "

ensures the existence and uniqueness of the solution of $(1)$ at least at one interval of the form $[0,b']$. Since $f$ satisfies the Lipschitz criterion in respect to $y$ in any interval of the form $[1-c,1+c]$, write $b'$ as a function of $c$.

That's what I have tried:

$$\left| \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}f(t,y) \right|=|2y| \leq M \Rightarrow -M \leq 2y \leq M  \Rightarrow \frac{-M}{2} \leq y \leq \frac{M}{2}$$

$$1+c=\frac{M}{2}\\1-c=-\frac{M}{2}$$

$$\Rightarrow c=\frac{M}{2}$$

$$L=M$$

Therefore $\exists L:=M \geq 0: \forall t \in [0,2] \ \forall y_1, y_2 \in \left [ 1-\frac{M}{2}, 1+\frac{M}{2}\right]$

$$|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)| \leq L|y_1-y_2|$$

So the ODE $(1)$ is solved uniquely, at least at the interval $[0,b']$.

$$A=\max_{0 \leq t \leq 2, 1-\frac{M}{2} \leq y \leq 1+\frac{M}{2}} |f(t,y)|=\max_{0 \leq t \leq 2, 1-\frac{M}{2} \leq y \leq 1+\frac{M}{2}} y^2=\left( 1+\frac{M}{2} \right)^2$$

$$b'=\min \{ 2, \frac{\frac{M}{2}}{\left( 1+\frac{M}{2}\right)^2}\}= \frac{M}{2\left( 1+\frac{M}{2}\right)^2}, \text{ since } M^2+3M+4>0, \forall M$$

$$b'=\frac{M}{2\left( 1+\frac{M}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{c}{1+c}$$

Could you tell me if it is right or if I have done something wrong?